# Quickest way to open dataset, count the records and return the number to a variable

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite

I'm pretty new to C#/WPF/SQLite and have created a form that will need to display several calculations (from two different tables).  I'd like to know what you guys think the fastest way to do this would be (and if anyone could provide a rough guide for the code - it would be a big help).

It's a bit rough (and not fully working), but here it is:

```
    string cs = ClsVariables.StrDb;
    using(SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(cs))
    {
        con.Open();
        string stm = "SELECT [ID] FROM tblActivities WHERE [Activity]='Sleeping'";
        using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(stm, con))
        {
            //I'm guessing this is where I need count the number of rows (but haven't figure that bit out just yet
        }
        con.Close();   
     }
```

Comment: Show please what you did.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The aggregate function [COUNT](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html) of SQL could solve you problem, but on the C# code you don't need to fill a dataset with a table and then count the rows found. Neither you need a SQLiteDateReader because when you expect your result to be just one row with only one column you use ExecuteScalar

```
string cmdText = "SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM tblActivities WHERE [Activity] = 'Sleeping'";
using(SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(cs))
using(SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(cmdText, con))
{
    con.Open();
    int count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
    Console.WriteLine("You have " + count.ToString() + " records sleeping");
}
```

A last note on ExecuteScalar. It could return NULL but, in your case (COUNT returns zero or a number > 0), this is not possible so I don't check the return value for null and I directly convert it to an integer

Comment: Thank you Steve (and The Mahahaj) - I really appreciate your help on this.  I'm pretty new to this site and have ticked your response, but is there anything else that I need to do that might help your reputation?  Thanks again - Andy

Comment: You could upvote the answers (more than one) that you find helpful. A last note on the answer. ExecuteScalar could return NULL but in your case this is no possible so I don't check the return value for null and directly convert it

Comment: Thanks Steve - will do.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the count of the dataset by adding the count as a column in your query:

```
    int count = 0;
    using(SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(cs))
    {
        con.Open();
        string stm = "select count(id) as count from tblActivities WHERE [Activity] = 'Sleeping'";
        using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(stm, con))
        {
            using (IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    if (reader["count"] != DBNull.Value && reader["count"] != null)
                    {
                        if (!int.TryParse(reader["count"], out count))
                        {
                            //failed to parse
                        }
                    }
                 }
            }
        }
        con.Close();   
     }
```